# GAS - Add line to found text with google slide api

Tags: google-slides-api

I have a slide and has some text box, I would like to search such text boxes and draw a line from start to end on found text.

Current API can get the startIndex and endIndex, but I do not found the API to get the startLocation and end Location.

Current sample code as below:

```
function addLines() {
  var myPresentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()
  var presentationId = myPresentation.getId();
  var slides = myPresentation.getSlides();
  var slide = slides[0];
  var slideId = slide.getObjectId();

var elems = slide.getPageElements()
for (var i in elems){
  var elem = elems[i];
   if(elem.getPageElementType() == "SHAPE"){
     var shape = elem.asShape()
     var text = elem.asShape().getText().find("hello")
     for (var j =0; j < text.length; j++){
          var start = text[j].getStartIndex();
          var end = text[j].getEndIndex();
          console.log(start,end)
          //addline(x,y)
       }
   }
  }
}

function addline(x,y) {
    var line = slide.insertLine(
        SlidesApp.LineCategory.CURVED,
        x,
        y
      );
}
```

Please comment if it's possible or not for such a special case!

Comment: What is `line` of `draw a line from start to end on found text.`? Is it the underline? If my understanding is correct, about `draw a line from start to end on found text.`, from your script, you want to add the underline to the text of `hello` of the searched text box. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: There's no API for char position on a slide, and I doubt it will ever be. Best you can do is workaround it by applying underline format to text instead of drawing a line.

Comment: by "startLocation and endLocation" do you mean the coordinates (eg. "{left: 10, top: 10}") of the characters you are searching for in the shape?

Comment: right, I would like to get the coordinate of start and end point.

Comment: None of the methods of the API allow for retrieving the coordinates of characters. Perhaps you'd like to create a feature request for it. You could do so [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191598&template=823918)